# Inequality with variable on the integral limits (incomplete gammas)

Tags: integration, inequality, gamma-function

I want to solve an inequality of the type:
$$\int_{x}^{+\infty} f(t) \cdot dt + \int_{0}^{x}  g(t) \cdot dt > 0$$
Is there a general-case solution for this with $f$ and $g$ known?

If not, is there a solution for the specific case
$$a \cdot \int_{x}^{+\infty} t^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-t\cdot\beta} \cdot dt - p\cdot \int_{0}^{x}  t^{\alpha}\cdot e^{-t\cdot\beta} \cdot dt > 0$$
where $a$, $p$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ are known constants?

Comment: If $p>0$ it looks like the left-hand side in your example will be negative for large $x$.

Comment: That is correct; I want to find the $x$ that are small enough that it won't be negative.